# Create Products TableView with PAGINATION and LIKE product feature in RxSwift MVVM

Tags: swift, mvvm, pagination, rx-swift

I have tried to develop a simple product listing app in RxSwift with MVVM design pattern. I have managed to achieve it but I need someone to review my code, such as:

1. Have I followed the proper RxSwift features?
2. Is binding of `TableViewCell`s item with `ViewController`'s `ViewModel` correct?
3. Anything I am missing here?

Note: Also, it is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/ajaybhanushalid2k/RxSwift_MVVM).

#### ViewController.swift

```
// MARK:- View's MVVM Binding Method
func configure(with viewModel: ViewModelType) {
    // DataSource implementation
    let dataSource = RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource<SectionOfProducts>(
        configureCell: { dataSource, tableView, indexPath, item in
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProductCell", for: indexPath) as! ProductCell
            cell.prepareCell(with: item)

            // Binding Cell item with viewModel's input
            cell.buttonLike.rx.tap
                .map{_ in item}
                .bind(to: self.viewModel.input.likedProduct)
                .disposed(by: cell.disposeBag)

            return cell
    })
    self.dataSource = dataSource

    // Binding reachedBottom trigger with viewModel's input for pagination of products
    tableViewProducts.rx.reachedBottom.asObservable()
        .bind(to: viewModel.input.nextPageTrigger)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    // Bind refresh control to viewModel
    refreshControl.rx.controlEvent(.valueChanged)
        .bind(to: self.viewModel.input.refreshTrigger)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    // Binding viewModel's output's products with tableview items
    viewModel.output.products.asObservable()
        .bind(to: tableViewProducts.rx.items(dataSource: dataSource))
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

#### ViewModel.swift

```
class ProductsViewModel: ViewModelProtocol {
    // Input consists of user inputs such as like any product, pull to refresh and get data for next page
    struct Input {
        let likedProduct: AnyObserver<ProductModel>
        let refreshTrigger: AnyObserver<Void>
        let nextPageTrigger: AnyObserver<Void>
    }

    // products are provided as output show on ViewController
    struct Output {
        let products: Driver<[SectionOfProducts]>
    }

    let input: Input
    let output: Output

    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    private let likedProductSubject = PublishSubject<ProductModel>()
    private let refreshTriggerSubject = PublishSubject<Void>()
    private let loadAfterTriggerSubject = PublishSubject<Void>()

    init(_ interactor: ProductsInteractorProtocol) {
        // Init Output
        input = Input(likedProduct: likedProductSubject.asObserver(),
                      refreshTrigger: refreshTriggerSubject.asObserver(),
                      nextPageTrigger: loadAfterTriggerSubject.asObserver())
        //>>>>>>>>>> Please review my code from here
        // When ViewModel initializes products are requested from the Interactor
        var products = interactor.getProducts()

        // Detect when like button is tapped in the ViewController's tableView's cell
        likedProductSubject.subscribe ({ (event) in
            print("\(String(describing: event.element?.productName))")
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)

        // To get next gage data I have used danielt1263/PaginationNetworkLogic.swift: Link: https://gist.github.com/danielt1263/10bc5eb821c752ad45f281c6f4e3034b
        let source = PaginationUISource(refresh: refreshTriggerSubject.asObservable(), loadNextPage: loadAfterTriggerSubject.asObservable(), bag: disposeBag)
        let sink = PaginationSink(ui: source, loadData: interactor.getNextProducts(page:))

        // Concat new products with the previous products
        let newProducts = sink.elements.asObservable()
        products = Observable.concat([products, newProducts]).scan([], accumulator: +)
        //<<<<<<<<<<<< Till here

        // Init Output
        output = Output(products: products.asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: []))
    }
}
```

#### ProductsInteractor.swift

```
final class ProductsInteractor: ProductsInteractorProtocol {

    var nextURLString: String?

    /// Sending a post request to get products
    ///
    /// - Returns: Array structured according to RxDataSources requirement
    func getProducts() -> Observable<[SectionOfProducts]> {
        var products: [ProductModel]?
        let requestData = ProductsRQM(categoryId: 0, subCategoryId: 0, typeId: 0, customerId: "11")
        return Observable.create { [weak self] (observer) -> Disposable in
            APIRequests.shared.post(requestModel: requestData, requestPath: .requestProducts) { (error, data) in
                let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                let responseModel = try? jsonDecoder.decode(ProductsBase.self, from: data!)

                // Products from the api are stored in products variable
                products = responseModel?.data?.item
                self?.nextURLString = responseModel?.data?.links?[0].href
                let section = [SectionOfProducts(header: "", items: products ?? [])]
                observer.onNext(section)
                observer.onCompleted()
            }
            return Disposables.create {}
        }
    }

    /// Sending a get request to get products
    ///
    /// - Returns: Array structured according to RxDataSources requirement
    func getNextProducts(page: Int) -> Observable<[SectionOfProducts]> {
        var products: [ProductModel]?
        return Observable.create { [weak self] (observer) -> Disposable in
            if self?.nextURLString != nil {
                APIRequests.shared.get(requestURL: self?.nextURLString ?? "", callBack: { (error, data) in
                    let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                    let responseModel = try? jsonDecoder.decode(ProductsBase.self, from: data!)

                    // Products from the api are stored in products variable
                    products = responseModel?.data?.item

                    // If true then nextPage is available else not
                    if responseModel?.data?.links?[0].rel != "previousPage" {
                        self?.nextURLString = responseModel?.data?.links?[0].href
                    } else { // Else assigning nextURLString to nil to prevent unnecessary api call
                        self?.nextURLString = nil
                    }
                    let section = [SectionOfProducts(header: "", items: products ?? [])]
                    observer.onNext(section)
                    observer.onCompleted()
                })
            }
            return Disposables.create {}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good first attempt and a lot of good can be said about it, but I'm going to focus on what I see are problems that should be fixed. Don't let this dissuade you though!

- `ControllerType` and `ViewModelProtocol` are completely useless. If you aren't going to use them to constrain some generic function then get rid of them.
- Your `APIRequests.get(requestURL:callBack:)` doesn't call the callBack if the requestURL can't be used to create a `URL`. This will cause silent errors. In general, make sure that all possible paths call the callBack when you are making async functions. Also, `RxCocoa` has a couple of wrappers around `dataTask`. I suggest you use them in your `APIRequests` class.
- `APIRequests` is a class with no state. This is pointless. Move the functions out of the class and get rid of it.
- `ProductsInteractor.nextURLString` is Optional. There is no point in making Strings optional. An empty string is the same as no string.
- `APIRequest` doesn't need to be a protocol; it's just a data bucket. Make it a `struct` and adjust other code as necessary.
- Regarding `ProductsViewModel`: I'm not a fan of this style of view model; It seems like a lot of boilerplate to me. In any case, you should have unit tests for it.
- Your `ProductsInteractor.getProducts()` and `ProductsInteractor.getNextProducts(page:)` functions only emit if the network request was successful, they never emit errors and if `self?.nextURLString == nil` then `getNextProducts(page:)` doesn't emit anything at all. In general, make sure that all possible paths through the block of an Observable.create all call the observer.